# CDC in Upsolver

Tags: sqlake, upsolver

How does CDC work in Upsolver?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer at a high level. A snapshot is taken when you add a new table to a data source. When the snapshot finishes, it is ingested in Upsolver (as Avro in s3). While the snapshot is ingested, changes from the replication slot are consumed (from the database) and once snapshots are finished, data is ingested in Upsolver (basically we would take the data from the S3 and route it to the streaming data source). These writes are also throttled on our end so you should typically not see any latency impacts if snapshotting large tables.